# mint 19.2 and how to install a hp printer

Tags: linux-mint

hello i have an HP laser jet M14-17 that i am trying to use with mint 19.2 whats the easiest way to install this printer i am a complete novice to mint and have only just got it set up a step by step guide would be nice.   many thanks   dave c

Comment: many thanks  sorry but i am struggling to find HPLIP Toolbox

Comment: if this is a "request for learning materials" then so is every other question on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Mint 19.2, by default, installs the hplip drivers for HP printer support. The GUI toolbox, however, is not. Run `sudo apt install hplip-gui`, then access the **HPLIP Toolbox** (from *Settings*).

If you're not comfortable with the Linux terminal, open **Software Manager** (under *System).* In the search box (upper right-hand corner), enter *hplip*. Select **HPLIP-GUI** and install.